# FontFamily and Size Method

Tags: c#

im using the  following method

```
  private void FontChange(FontFamily f, int Syze) 
  {
      Font font = new Font ( f , Syze );
  }
```

then if i want to use the method
i call

```
FontChange("Consolas",11);
```

Which gives me the error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'ContactList.Main.FontChange(System.Drawing.FontFamily, int)' has some
>   invalid arguments.

Comment: Consider calling your second parameter `size` rather than `Syze`; it both matches common conventions (parameter names are typically not capitalized in C#) and is spelled correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be declared as:

```
    private void FontChange(string f, int Syze)
    {
        Font font = new Font(f, Syze);
    }
```

Comment: Can you also help me with this how do i convert ALL UPPERCASE TO titlecase?

Comment: @suffix: what do you mean with titlecase? Lowercase? Only first char uppercase? Anyway, this is another question I think ;)

Comment: only first letter uppercase Lol

Comment: @suffix: something like `char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);`, but you have to test if string is empty or null and if its length is more than one. Now, accept my answer and close this post :)